# How to check if input textbox or tab is focused using nodejs socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

The chat code below is working fine. Now am trying to check if the other end user  that am chatting with if her form input textbox and window tab is on focus or not

**Here is my issue and scenario**

two users are chating**(Mr.A and Mr.B)** now **Mr.A** want to check or know if the form input textbox or window tab of **Mr.B**
is on focus

i have tried this two set of code but its but it keeps telling me **no new message** each time I post a message

```
if(inputfocus_check){
// If the other end user is on input form chat box is focus, there's no need to show there's a new message
        document.title = "No new Message";

    }else{

        // If the other end user input form chat box is not on focus, show there's a new message
        document.title = "New message just arrive";
    }
```

and

```
if (window.onfocus) {
        // If the other end user is on focus, there's no need to show there's a new message
        document.title = "No new Message";

    }else{

        // If the other end user is on another tab, show there's a new message
        document.title = "New message just arrive";
    }
```

here is **server.js**

```
// Register events on socket connection
io.on('connection', function(socket){ 
  socket.on('chatMessage', function(from, msg){
    io.emit('chatMessage', from, msg);
  });
```

**index.js**

```
var socket = io(); 
function submitfunction(){
  var from = $('#user').val();
  var message = $('#m').val();

  socket.emit('chatMessage', from, message);
$('#m').val('').focus();
  return false;
}

socket.on('chatMessage', function(from, msg){
  $('#messages').append('<li><b style="color:' + color + '">' + from + '</b>: ' + msg + '</li>');


var inputfocus_check = $('#m').val('').focus();
if(inputfocus_check){
// If the other end user is on input form chat box is focus, there's no need to show there's a new message
        document.title = "No new Message";

    }else{

        // If the other end user input form chat box is not on focus, show there's a new message
        document.title = "New message just arrive";
    }


/*
if (window.onfocus) {
        // If the other end user is on focus, there's no need to show there's a new message
        document.title = "No new Message";

    }else{

        // If the other end user is on another tab, show there's a new message
        document.title = "New message just arrive";
    }

*/


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text focus issue is resolved using `document.activeElement`

as per code below

```
var el = document.getElementById('m');
// check for focus
var isFocused = (document.activeElement === el);


 if (isFocused){
    alert("focused");
  }else{
    alert("not focused")
}
```